# Remove Unused JS/CSS bundles Code Splitting Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, code-splitting

I hope I can keep this brief.

The basic jist of my issue stems from SASS imports.

I have an `App` Component that handles all the routing.

In the imports is a `Login` Component. In this component is an a `.scss` import

```
import './Login.scss';
```

In this file is imports of various other `.scss` files.

Another route in my `App` component is `ForgotPassword` component.

Similar to `Login` it has a `.scss` import of its own.

Now, the issue is, if a user loads the `Login` component, it means that all the css and imports are stored in a css file and that carries over to every other component in my project.

Let's say one of the `.scss` imports was something like `Card` which styles `.Card` classes. I have a variable

`$Card-padding: 15px !default;`

In `ForgetPassword` I also have that import. First issue is that I now have two imports of `Card` and if I try to override the `$Card-padding` variable it will also override on `Login`.

I am currently using `react-loadable` in my `App` component where I handle my routes.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import './App.scss';

const Login = Loadable({
   loader: () => import('../../login/Login'),
   loading() {
      return null;
   }
});

const ForgotPassword = Loadable({
   loader: () => import('../../forgot-password/ForgotPassword'),
   loading() {
      return null;
   }
});

const App = () => {

   return (
      <div className="App">
         <Router>
            <div className="App-container">
            <Switch>
               <Route path="/login" component={() => <Login />} exact />
               <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={() => <ForgotPassword />} exact />
            </Switch>
            </div>
         </Router>
      </div>
   );

}

export default App;
```

My question really is, can I remove unused CSS with React and Webpack, or is there a better method of css containment so that it cannot be accessed outside of the component?

I feel like this is something that lots of people do, but I cannot seem to find out how to do this. There may be a term that I have missed which would lead be to the correct resources. But I am lost. I'm not a huge fan of css in js, a lot of the styling comes from another project that is similar so is much simpler to copy it over other than having to write css in js for each class and permutation.

Every question on this on here does not have an accepted answer, so I'm throwing a Hail Mary in the hopes that someone has a React/Webpack solution to this.

I had tried `ExtractTextPlugin` in webpack, but it never seemed to spit out the `Login.scss`, so I may have configured it incorrectly. I am currently using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to compile my `scss` files.

Comment: I had tried that, it seemed to keep the `.Card` class regardless of what path I redirected to as it was used in both perhaps? Not really the solution I was hoping for

Answer (score 1):

> if I try to override the $Card-padding variable it will also override
>   on Login.

I don't believe you should be selectively overriding sass variables.

To override a css property, why not add specific css class for that component:

```
// global styles
.card {
    padding: $Card-padding;
}
```

login.scss:

```
$mynewpadding: 100px;

.card.login {
    // override the default padding here
    padding: $mynewpadding;
}
```

forgottenpassword.scss:

```
$myothernewpadding: 30px;

.card.forgottenpassword {
    // overrider the default padding here
    padding: $myothernewpadding;
}
```

imho the above would be much clearer and easier to maintain..

Comment: While I do sort of agree (and may just have to be the way I go about it) it's much easier to write one line `$Card-padding: 10px` than writing `$myothernewpadding: 30px;

.card.forgottenpassword {
    padding: $myothernewpadding;
}` for everywhere card is used, which in this case will be on every one of the 15 Components, granted, in most components it will be the same but not all and that is just for card not the other imports we use. It also how we do it currently in a JSP project, so easier for everyone to transition over.

Comment: I don't think there is anyway around it - unless you want to have the global css compiled for each component! Another option is to add modifiers to .card so that you can use .card.small .card.medium and .card.large etc

Comment: Yes, I think modifiers are probably the way to go in the meantime, thanks for the help